# I am unable to get the correct value from the ngrx store in a simple angular app

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I want that when an API call returns a user the state is updated and the home.component.html shows the new value. I am also using ngrx devtools and I can see the state change, but the html does not update. This is what I have.

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  meUser$ = this.store.select(selectMeUser);

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(loadMeUser());
  }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<p *ngIf="meUser$ | async as me">
   Hi, {{ me.firstname }}
</p>
```

**user.actions.ts**

```
export const loadMeUser = createAction('[User] Load Me User');
export const loadMeUserSuccess = createAction(
    '[User] Load Me User Success', 
    props<{ user: User }>()
);
export const loadMeUserFailure = createAction(
    '[User] Load Me User Failure',
    props<{ error: string }>()
);
```

**user.reducers.ts**

```
export interface UserState {
    meUser: User | null; 
    status: string;
    error: string;
}

export const initialstate: UserState = {
    meUser: null,
    status: 'pending',
    error: ''
}

export const userReducer = createReducer(
    initialstate, 
    on(loadMeUser, (state) => ({ ...state, status: 'loading' as StatusType })),
    on(loadMeUserSuccess, (state, { user }) => ({
        ...state, 
        meUser: user,
        error: '',
        status: 'success'
    })),
    on(loadMeUserFailure, (state, { error }) => ({
        ...state, 
        error: error, 
        status: 'error'
    }))
)
```

**user.selectors.ts**

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.user;
export const selectMeUser = createSelector(
    selectUser,
    (state: UserState) => state?.meUser
)
```

**user.effects.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<AppState>,
        private userService: UserService
    ) {}

    loadMeUser$ = createEffect(() => 
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadMeUser),
            exhaustMap(() => {
                return this.userService.getMeUser().pipe(
                    map((data) => {
                        return loadMeUserSuccess({ user: data });
                    }),
                    catchError((error) => of(loadMeUserFailure({ error: error })))
                )
            })
        )
    )
}
```

In the devtools I can see the state result is success and if I add a console.log inside the effect the data is correct, if I change it to `meUser$ = this.store.select(selectMeUser).subscribe((data) => console.log(data))` I get undefinied.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ users: userReducer }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
      trace: true,
      traceLimit: 25
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([UserEffects])
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, ...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're calling `this.store.select` outside of `ngOnInit`, so I suspect a DI issue. Try moving the instantiation of `meUser$` into your `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: @WillAlexander I declared `meUser$: Observable<User> | null = null;` outside of ngOnInit and `this.meUser$ = this.store.select(selectMeUser);` inside it, but it isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.user;
```

`user` should be `userS`:

```
export const selectUser = (state: AppState) => state.users;
```

The reason is that it's configured as `users` while configuring the store:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ users: userReducer }),
```

To prevent this, you can make use of feature keys https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#selecting-feature-states
or build your state with feature creators https://ngrx.io/guide/store/feature-creators

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user state isn't linked to the module.

Did you add the `StoreModule.forFeature('user', userReducer),` in your module?

Comment: sorry, forgot to share the app module, I edited the question and added it